# With AsciiDoc, how to force extra carriage return whitespace before headers?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, hugo

I have a problem where the proper space before my headings, aka after a definition item, does not appear. (I think I cannot post a picture here.)

Here is some of the asciidoc. The "== What not to do" is a heading, but it is squished up next to the prior text. Does anyone see my bug or a fix? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: You could fix this by add your own stylesheet and docheader, though it wouldn't fix the preview output in atom it looks like. What does the final output look like when you generate?

Comment: Hmm, is there a sample of that?  Tthe final output is on the right in my pic.

Comment: Sorry, I had the name wrong, it's a docinfo file. Take a look at http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file